# I want to install another Windows on my PC, what should I be careful about?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, windows-installation

I have Windows 7 on one parition of my disk. I have two or more other empty partitions.

Is there anything specific I need to pay more attention to, in order not to ruin my current system?

Answer (score 0):

Install the oldest version first, followed by newer versions

You have Windows 7, would advise that you install another copy of 7, or 8

Installing an older version would require you to mess around with the bootloader to restore access to the newer one

And, **BACKUP YOUR DATA**

Answer (score 0):

Data-loss is most likely during partitioning, and if something goes wrong with the boot-setup you might not have the right backup anyway (But that information should be easy to backup?).

Though it is better to set up a backup system before than after (Perhaps have the most important files backed up in the cloud).

Also you should think about how your system is partitioned, perhaps make the system drive lean by moving pagefile, tempfiles, data etc off the system drive.

Answer (score -1):

Most importantly you should backup all data that you do not want to lose.

What do you mean by "ruin my current system"?

Installing a new version of Windows will interfere with any existing software installations as you will have to reinstall applications like MS Office.

Comment: He's talking about installing Windows on the two other empty partitions.

Answer (score -1):

While it is always good to backup your data, I personally wouldn't bother.

Just make sure you select the correct partition when you go to install Windows :)